# Does current pass through earthed resistor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

Did there is a potential drop and current in a resistor when both sides of resistor earthed? Note the above setup 
is connected to battery. https://photos.app.goo.gl/MuQ72r1UHYWmZJE2A

Comment: You need to show the setup

Answer (score 1):

You did not attach any circuit diagram.

However, if both sides of the resistor are connected to ground then the resistor is effectively shorted out. Hence, no current will flow through it

In real life, as always, this will be slightly different. Even if the resistor is shorted out, the resistance of the short will not be exactly zero, and hence there will be a small voltage across, and a small current through the resistor. In normal circumstances you can ignore this as, it is minuscule compared to the other currents.

EDIT

I had a look at your circuit, and R3 is indeed shorted out. That leaves the battery connected to ground via 2 parallel resistors, R1 and R2. Hence, as stated above, in an ideal case no current flows through R3.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the “wires” shown in the circuit are zero resistance and the arrows point to a common electrical point (same electrical potential), be it earth or otherwise, then R3 can be considered short-circuited (zero voltage across and zero current through R3).

Hope this helps.